# Check for duplicating data in database android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i have application with database
i want to checking data from database before entering in database
if data equal from database it is can't entering,if data not equal can entering
this is my some code :

```
public void saveData(){
    long tim = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
    String curTime = df.format(tim);
    Cursor c = helper.getNoOrder();
    c.moveToFirst();
    if(c.getCount() != 0){
        System.out.println("klik");
        if(noOrder.getText().toString().equals(c.getString(0))){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Order Sudah Terdaftar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            helper.insertBeli123(noOrder.getText().toString(), item.getText().toString(), 
                    custName.getText().toString(), custTelp.getText().toString(),
                    qty.getText().toString(),temp.getText().toString(),temp.getText().toString(),
                    temp.getText().toString(), curTime);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data berhasil disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }else{
        helper.insertBeli123(noOrder.getText().toString(), item.getText().toString(), 
                custName.getText().toString(), custTelp.getText().toString(),
                qty.getText().toString(),temp.getText().toString(),temp.getText().toString(),
                temp.getText().toString(), curTime);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data berhasil disimpan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
    //startActivity(new Intent(this,Direktori.class));
}
```

in my DBhelper like this :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tanda_terima (_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,no_order text " +
            ",item text,cust_id text,cust_name text,cust_telp text,quantity text,order_nik text" +
            ",pengirim text,penerima text,gambar text,waktu_ambil datetime,flag integer)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE image (_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,no_order text ,image text,tgl_buat datetime,flag integer)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE user (user text primary key,no_imei integer,password text)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE log_sync_tanda (no_order text primary key,status text ,waktu_sync datetime)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE log_sync_image (image text primary key,kdstore text,status text ,waktu_sync datetime)");
}
 public void insertBeli123(String no_order,String item,String cust_name
        ,String cust_telp,String quantity,String pengirim,String penerima,
        String gambar,String waktu){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("no_order", no_order);
    cv.put("item", item);
    cv.put("cust_name", cust_name);
    cv.put("cust_telp", cust_telp);
    cv.put("quantity", quantity);
    cv.put("pengirim", pengirim);
    cv.put("penerima", penerima);
    cv.put("gambar", gambar);
    cv.put("waktu_ambil", waktu);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("tanda_terima", "name", cv);
}
    public Cursor getNoOrder(){
    return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT no_order FROM tanda_terima", null));
}
```

Comment: can you give me some example @ariefbayu

Comment: my primary key is _id,,how can i add unique in no_order??

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code. it help you check duplicate data.

```
String sql = "select * from "
                + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE placeId = '" + placeId + "'"; 
        Cursor cursorinfo = null; 
        try {
            database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            cursorinfo = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!cursorinfo.moveToFirst()) {
                        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            try {
                database.insert(TABLE_NAME, "", values/// Here ContentValues);
            } finally {
                database.close();
                cursorinfo.close();
            }
        }
```

I think it help you.
 Thanks

Comment: Hi, Here you want . I write this code another class not activity or DatabaseHelper class. After rawQuery check that  Cursor MoveFirst or not. if Cursor do not MoveFirst then this data are already in database.

Answer (score 0):

Here initially you need to fetch entire data from the database in cursor

```
 void insertInDatabase()
 {
    Cursor cursor=fetchDataFromDatabase();
    if(!cursor.getCount==0)
    {
         while(cursor.moveToNext())
          {
               if(!(cursor.getString(1).equals("Harneet"))
               {
                     dbAdapter.insert("Harneet");
                     return;
               }
          }
          System.println("Record ALready exists in Database");
    }
    else
    {
              System.println("Empty Database");
              dbAdapter.insert("Harneet");
    }
  }

    /*Assume that we have two fields in database, one is Primary key and other is Name field*/
```

In DbHelper write this :

Inserting values in database

```
     void insert(String name)
     { 
           ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
           cv.put("NAME",name);
           getWritableDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
     }
```

Fetching Cursor values

```
     public Cursor fetchDataFromDatabase()
     {
          String col[]={_id,name};
         getReadableDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME,col,null,null,null);
     }
```